# opencv close camera

Tags: opencv, c++-cli

ok I have this code

```
IplImage *frame;
CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
cvSaveImage("sample.jpg",frame);
cvReleaseImage(&frame);
```

which saves an image, but after saving that image, I want to release that camera so that it closes. Now the camera stays on until the program stops, I want to relase and close the camera  exactly after `cvReleaseImage(&frame);`

I tried

> cvReleaseCapture(&capture)

but it gives me a runtime error: `the application has requested the Runtime to terminate in an unusual way` and this error

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (unrecognized or unsupported array type)
>   in unknown function, file ......\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line
>   996

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not completely sure. But try removing the cvReleaseImage call.

I remember that the image-pointer retrieved by the cvQueryImage method points allways at the same adress. so my guess is that this image-data is managed by the capture. so releasing it is done when you release the capture.

EDIT:

found here:
http://opencv.jp/opencv-1.0.0_org/docs/ref/opencvref_highgui.htm

> The function cvQueryFrame grabs a frame from camera or video file,
>   decompresses and returns it. This function is just a combination of
>   cvGrabFrame and cvRetrieveFrame in one call. The returned image should
>   not be released or modified by user.

Answer (score 0):

Tried `cvReleaseCapture()`? 
(30 characters.)

Comment: ok, what would come between brackets cause cvReleaseCapture(&capture) gives me a runtime error: the application has requested the Runtime to terminate in an unusual way

Comment: ok this is the exact error: OpenCV Error: Bad argument (unrecognized or unsupported array type) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 996 thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're looking for is [cvReleaseCapture](http://opencv.jp/opencv-1.0.0_org/docs/ref/opencvref_highgui.htm#decl_cvReleaseCapture). There's  the code that worked for me:

`int main (void) {`

```
  IplImage *frame;
  CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
  frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
  cvSaveImage("sample.jpg",frame);
  cvReleaseImage(&frame);
  cvReleaseCapture( &capture );

  return 0;
}
```

It's a quite a simple code, but it should terminate properly, without any error raised.

Comment: ok, what would come between brackets cause cvReleaseCapture(&capture) gives me a runtime error: the application has requested the Runtime to   terminate in an unusual way

Comment: Are you sure it crashes just after cvReleaseCapture(&capture) ? It works fine for me.

Comment: yes just after cvReleaseCapture do you run the latest release of opencv? Do you do something with capture, do you set it to zero or sanything else? The code I posted doesn't work for me

Comment: Not the latest: I'm using Opencv 2.2. And I don't do anything with the capture